# Java/Swing: low-profile button height?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I would like to reduce the vertical size of a JButton. The following code works fine for K > 1 but I can't seem to reduce the size. Any suggestions?

```
JButton button = /* ... get button here ... */
Dimension d = button.getPreferredSize();
d.setSize(d.getWidth(), d.getHeight()*K);
button.setPreferredSize(d);
```

**edit:** I'm using JavaBuilders + MigLayout. It looks like I have to do `button.setMaxSize(d);` instead of setPreferredSize(), not sure why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few options:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class FrameTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame("Demo");
        jf.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        // Ordinary button
        jf.add(new JButton("button 1"));

        // Smaller font
        jf.add(new JButton("button 2") {{ setFont(getFont().deriveFont(7f)); }});

        // Similar to your suggestion:
        jf.add(new JButton("button 3") {{
            Dimension d = getPreferredSize();
            d.setSize(d.getWidth(), d.getHeight()*.5);
            setPreferredSize(d);
        }});

        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.pack();
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Produces

[image]

Comment: Caveat: [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513)?

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative, some L&Fs (e.g. *Nimbus*, *Aqua*) support a `JComponent.sizeVariant`, as discussed in [*Resizing a Component*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/size.html) and [*Using Client Properties*](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/tn2007/tn2196.html#USING_PROPERTIES). Several variations are illustrated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14599176/230513).

[image]

Comment: Any chance of getting one of your lovely Aqua PLAF images for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54822330/418556)? I might have asked you to submit an answer, but it's been closed. 

Answer (score 4):

Maybe just play with the Border of the button:

```
Insets insets = button.getInsets();
insets.top = 0;
insets.bottom = 0;
button.setMargin( insets );
```