# My JComponents are hogging too many pixels

Tags: java, swing, layout, padding, pixel

I am trying to prune off unecessary pixels on an existing Java Swing UI. It uses GridbagConstrains mostly, but some other LayoutManagers too. A lot of the components are just added to containers and by default they'll pad themselves with 10 extra pixels on each side. For example, with the GridBagConstrains, I have a checkBox that is padded with way too many pixels on each side by default. I set the ipadxy and insets to 0, but it had no effect. Can anyone offer some general tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `JCheckBox` may have a default border that pads the component out some.  Try setting a zero-width empty border on the checkbox, I think that will help:

```
checkBox.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
```

**Edit**

For JPanels, make sure their layout manager is not adding padding.  A common case is `new JPanel()`.  By default the layout for a JPanel is a BorderLayout with some horizontal and vertical gap. Instead, use `new JPanel(new BorderLayout())` which still uses a border layout, but the horizontal and vertical gap will be zero

Also, JPanels and JToolBars are both containers, keep in mind their children may have non-empty borders by default as well (for example, a JButton added to a JToolBar)

Comment: Thanks that fixed my problem with JCheckboxes, but what about JToolBars and JPanels, they seem to have natural padding and this didn't fix those components,

Answer (score 1):

Using GridBagConstraints set `weightx` and `weighty` of the components to 0.

Then add an invisible component e.g. `new JLabel()` to your panel with `weightx` and `weighty` of 1.

Answer (score 1):

Some L&Fs (e.g. *Nimbus*, *Aqua*) support a `JComponent.sizeVariant`, as discussed in [*Resizing a Component*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/size.html) and [*Using Client Properties*](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/tn2007/tn2196.html#USING_PROPERTIES).

At the same time, be wary of overcrowding. Also consider alternate designs, including tabbed pane, card layout, tool bar, palette and modeless dialog. See also this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899935/java-swing-low-profile-button-height).

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the [`Insets`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#insets) too?