# How use a 9-patch image as background on a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, nine-patch

I'm searching a way for use a [9-patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) file as background for javax.swing.JPanel.
So that the background image automatically resizes itself when the dimensions of the JPanel change.

Is it possible? Or I have to create all the pieces of the image and manually resize some of them when the listener triggers (like in the piece of code that follows)?

```
public class JPanelWithNinePatchBackground extends JPanel { 
{ 
    /* Define all parts of the background like BufferedImage */

    addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() { 
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) { 

            // Resize images . . . 

            JPanelWithBackground.this.repaint(); 
        } 
    });

    /* . . . */

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use either of the [`drawImage()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29) implementations that let you specify the corners of the destination rectangle. The method will complete faster if the source and destination rectangles match in size. [`RCTile`](http://sourceforge.net/p/robotchase/code/67/tree/trunk/src/org/gcs/robot/RCTile.java) is an example.

Comment: Works, but this is not what I want.
This solution resizes also the corners, and this should **not** happen with 9-patch files!

Comment: Based on your comment, I'm guessing you want something like [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html); I'm not aware of an existing component, but `drawImage()` automatically scales to the destination rectangle.

Comment: `drawImage()` scales the all rectangle.
I don't want this. What I want is to use [9-patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) images like on Android. 
Solution that doesn't scale the all rectangle but just some defined parts for let the scaled image perfectly fit the area but keeping corners unchanged. If I wasn't clear enough the link will help you.

Comment: Swing doesn't have such a component; you'll have to clarify your use case, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14599176/230513).

Comment: So ok, I have to create my own implementation like in the piece of code that I posted. 

Thanks for your time.