# Sea Glass Look and Feel: changing default button size?

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

I'm using [Sea Glass Look and Feel](http://seaglasslookandfeel.com) for my application, which uses a - for my purposes - quite large default button size. I'd like to have all buttons a bit smaller. The L&F supports [client properties](http://seaglass.googlecode.com/svn/doc/client-properties.html) - but do I have to change set this property for **each** button manually? Or is there a way to set a different (smaller) default size that is used for all created JButtons?

Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Comment: Try this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14599176/230513).

Comment: If I understood that example right, you have to repeat this for **each** button (wonder where my "each" in the posting is gone, I thought I also already wrote it above...). What I would like to do is to set a kind of "default small size" for each new created button (using Sea Glass Look and Feel).

Comment: Right; it's not a UI default; `createVariant()` is a factory method that can be invoked as required.