# How do I change a JButton height if I'm using the seaglass look and feel?

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

I'm using the seaglass look and feel in my application. How do I set the height for a JButton?
It seems like there is no way to have a custom height. I took a look at the documentation:
http://seaglass.googlecode.com/svn/doc/client-properties.html
and I tought I had to use JComponent.sizeVariant = scale to solve the problem, but it doesn't work.
How can I solve this?

Thanks trashgod, I tried this:

```
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassLookAndFeel");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JButton button = new JButton("Test");
    button.putClientProperty("JComponent.sizeVariant", "scale");

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    panel.add(button);
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 400));

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setContentPane(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

but doesn't seem to work either. Thanks anyway for your effort.

Answer (score 3):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14599176/230513), [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/size.html) and [here](http://seaglass.googlecode.com/svn/doc/client-properties.html), the `JComponent.sizeVariant` property value is a `String`, e.g. "mini", "small", "regular" and "large". For "scale" to work, the enclosing panel's layout must allow the component to resize. In the [variation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14599176/230513) below, `GridLayout` is used:

```
f.add(variantPanel("scale"));
…
private static JPanel variantPanel(String size) {
    JPanel variantPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout());
    …
    return variantPanel;
}
```

[image]

Comment: This isn't working the way I expected, but the example may be useful to you.

Comment: @emanuele: Sorry; I'd say leave the question open for a time in hopes of a better answer; I'm wary of [`setPreferredSize`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513).

Comment: it should have been panel.setPreferredSize, but I don't think it changes much. I edited the question anyway.

Comment: @emanuele: It may help to focus on the broader goal. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Your frame contains one panel. When you pack the frame the panel will be sized at 500x400, i.e., its preferred size. Your panel uses a BorderLayout. BorderLayout does not use the button preferred size. It will expand the button to fill the entire panel size. Try using a layout for your panel that respects the preferred size of its components, e.g., FlowLayout. If you want to change the button size you can then set the button's preferred size.