# Custom size button in java JInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

I am making a simple GUI in swing. I have a `JInternalFrame` and in this frame I have added two button but their size is beyond my expectation. I want to see these button in my size but their size is not getting changed. I have also use `setSized()` funtionj. Here the output-[image: output of program]

this is my code

```
/*making of sign in headerFrame and all its dimension and size and location are initialized here*/
 JInternalFrame signframe=new JInternalFrame("signframe", false, false, false, false);
 signframe.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1,5,6));
 signframe.putClientProperty("JInternalFrame.isPalette", Boolean.TRUE);
 signframe.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.NONE);
 BasicInternalFrameTitlePane signtitlePane =
         (BasicInternalFrameTitlePane) ((BasicInternalFrameUI) signframe.getUI()).getNorthPane();  
 signframe.remove(signtitlePane);
 signframe.setBorder(null);
 signframe.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
 signframe.setSize(250, 150);
 //end of the sign frame

 //location of the sign frame in the screen
 signframe.setLocation(30,60);

 //make the gui for the Sign frame
 //make sign button for the sign frame
 JButton signbutton=new JButton("SIGN IN");
 signbutton.setSize(20, 20);
 JButton signbutton2=new JButton("SIGN IN2");
 signbutton.setSize(20, 20);
 signbutton.resize(30, 40);
 signbutton2.setPreferredSize(getSize());

 //add action lister to the sign in button
 signbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});


 //adding the signbutton to signframe
 signframe.add(signbutton);
 signframe.add(signbutton2);

 //making the sign frame visible
 signframe.setVisible(true);
 //adding the sign frame into the destop pane
 desktoppane.add(signframe);


 //should be in the ends
 c.add(desktoppane);
 setVisible(true);
```

Comment: And your question is?  Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)  The size of a button can be changed by changing the font size, or setting a margin.

Comment: ..of course `signframe.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1,5,6));` the `GridLayout` will stretch components to fill the space available, but post an MCVE as suggested by @MadProgrammer.

Comment: Also consider `JComponent.sizeVariant`, seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14599176/230513).