# How to Layout the JComponents Whenever resolution of Frame changes?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jcomponent

How to layout the JComponents by resolution of **JPanel** or **JFrame**?

Hello, I'm new to java coding and I'm having problem layoutting components 
in **JPanel**.
Is there Good way to reset the size and location of components **whenever Frame's resolution changes**?
here is my code.

```
public class TestPanel extends JPanel{

private GameBoard SuperFrame; 
/*SuperFrame is JFrame where this Panel attach to..*/

public TestPanel(GameBoard SuperFrame) {
             .....
    this.SuperFrame=SuperFrame;
    this.setLayout(null);
    .......
    add(new Maximizebutton());
            ........
}

  private class MaxmizeButton extends MYUI{
 /*MYUI is abstract class which extends JComponent, and it inherits 
  preferredSize,preferredLocation and abstract void method revalidateSize ...*/

    JButton maxButton;
    public MaxmizeButton (){ 
        preferredSize = new Dimension(SuperFrame.getWidth()/10,SuperFrame.getHeight()/10);
        /*This is my crude solution about setting the size of Component
        by resolution of SuperFrame(JFrame) :( */

        preferredLocation = new Point();
        /*Is there good way to set or calculate the location of this component? */

        this.setSize(preferredSize);
        this.setLocation(preferredLocation);
        maxButton = new JButton("최대화");
        maxButton.setSize(preferredSize);
        maxButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                SuperFrame.MaxmizeFrame();
             /*MaximizeFrame method maximizes the SuperFrame..*/
            }
        });
        add(maxButton,0);
        }

    @Override
    void revalidateSize() {
        /*whenever resolution of SuperFrame changes this method will be called 
        and should change the size and location of Components Ideally..*/

        preferredSize = new Dimension(SuperFrame.getWidth()/10,SuperFrame.getHeight()/10);
        preferredLocation = new Point();
        this.setSize(preferredSize);
        this.setLocation(preferredLocation);
        maxButton.setSize(preferredSize);
      }
    }
}
```

I want to **resize all Components** in Panel by resolution of JFrame.
But couldn't found good solution for that.

Comment: I would choose a suitable LayoutManager for this instead of doing it manually. Have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html. You could have especially a look at http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/forms/ where you can define which and how the child elements have to grow when parent dimensions change.

Comment: Are you looking for `JComponent.sizeVariant`, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14599176/230513)?