# Howto change JButton Size

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, preferredsize

I am doing a euromillion program and i need some help. I have this code and i would like to set a size for the JButton. I dont know how to do it

Can someone tell me what do i have to change?

```
static JButton[][] botoes = new JButton[5][10];
static JButton [][] estrelas = new JButton[4][3];

public void grafica(){
    GridLayout layoutBotoes = new GridLayout(5,10);
    GridLayout layoutEstrelas = new GridLayout(4,3);
    um.setLayout(layoutBotoes);
    dois.setLayout(layoutEstrelas);
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){  
        for(l=0;l<10;l++){  
            cont++;
            botoes[i][l] = new JButton(""+cont);
            um.add(botoes[i][l]); 
            botoes[i][l].addActionListener(this);
        } 
    }  
    cont=0;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){  
        for(l=0;l<3;l++){ 
            if(i==3 && l==2) {
                break;
            } else {
                cont++;
                estrelas[i][l] = new JButton(""+cont); 
                dois.add(estrelas[i][l]); 
                estrelas[i][l].addActionListener(this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what _exactly_ do you want to achieve?

Comment: i want to put a size for the JButton

Comment: no, that's not what you want :-) In Swing/AWT, sizing and locating is the task of the LayoutManager, always. Your tasks are a) define the visuals of your ui (relative positioning/alignment/resizing behehaviour) b) find a LayoutManager that suits your requirements

Comment: i dont get it! My jButton are to big i want them smaller

Comment: read the tutorial chapter on LayoutManager (click the tab "info" and follow the swing tutorial link) to understand which manager does what (hint: GridLayout makes all components the same size and uses all the space available)

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use one of the approaches shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14589119/230513) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2899935/230513).

[image]