# How to use JPanel object with class extended?

Tags: java, swing, object, jpanel

I have a class `Main`, which I'm calling all my classes that extend `JPanel`. So, just do:

```
Frame.add(new JPanel)
```

Knowing, that such class extends `JPanel`. However, I cannot use object `JPanel` in that class. I tried to create an object of the class using `new`, but it does not work to add some component. Just works the of ways: `add`, because it is an extended class.

Main Class:

```
private void initialize() 
{

    tab = new JTabbedPane();
    frame.add(new JScrollPane(tab));
    frame.setTitle(TITLE);
    frame.setSize(800,500);
    frame.add(new ToolBar);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setJMenuBar(getJMenuBar());
    frame.setVisible(true);



}
```

In this class, I'm called my `Toolbar` class and add it to `JFrame`.

My ToolBar Class:

```
public class ToolBar extends JPanel {

private JToolBar toolbar;
private JButton icon;

/**
 * 
 * @param tab
 */
public ToolBar()
{

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(setJToolBar(),BorderLayout.NORTH); // add JToolbar to panel
    setBackground(getColor()); // sets up color for panel.



}

/**
 * Sets setJButtonNewFileIcon with icon
 * @return
 * JButton
 */
private JButton setJButtonNewFileIcon()
{
    icon = new JButton();
    icon.setBorder(border);
    icon.setBackground(getColor());
    icon.setToolTipText("New File");
    icon.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("icons/new.png")));

    return icon;

}
```

Now, I going to create an `ActionListener` to search. So, I want to add that `ActionListener` to that `JPanel` (`ToolBar`). However, I do not have object that class for that.

Comment: Could you show a snippet of code, or even better a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Your class is a jpanel once you extend it. Therefore you need to create a new Jframe `frame.add(this)` to access the inherited methods from the jpanel simply type `this.themethodyouwanttocall()`

Answer (score 2):

> I created an `ActionListener`.

Use [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) to encapsulate the functionality of your `JToolBar` components, as suggested in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16121288/230513).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to extend `JPanel` in order to fit your needs:

```
class SpecialPanel extends JPanel{

  public SpecialPanel(){
    super();
    // some more logic in constructor 
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    // override paint() for example
  }

}
```

Then you can use your custom `JPanel` elsewhere:

```
JFrame f = new JFrame("Hello World");
f.add(new SpecialPanel());
```

Comment: If you correctly deduced what he meant given what he wrote I will +1 this, I didn't understand much, hopefully someone did and edits OP.

Comment: Ditch the `paint` method...`paintComponent` is the recommended and preferred method for performing custom painting