# Nimbus - Different JProgressBar Styles

Tags: java, swing, styles, jprogressbar, nimbus

I was wondering how I could set my JProgressBar to use the two available styles, as NetBeans does.

I've noticed in NetBeans, that when debugging or building a program, the progress bar at the bottom-right of the screen first uses the indeterminate style, but with blocks instead of the oscillations and then switches over to the 'standard' style.

I'd like my program to use the oscillating style when the server is starting,

[image]

and then the blocks style when the server is running.

[image]

How could I achieve this?

Pictures:

[Blocks Style](http://team-m4gkbeatz.eu/Beatsleigher/Other/JProgBar_Blocks.PNG)
[Standard Style](http://team-m4gkbeatz.eu/Beatsleigher/Other/JProgBar_Oscillations.PNG)

Comment: I'd be to use JLayer instead to bothering with CustomUI, maybe is this component and its UI accessible for free usage, you have to check

Comment: Could be an artifact; also consider a [`sizeVariant`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2900157/230513).